# convert double value into DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a double value
 Ex:

```
double currentDate = 20161011;
```

Unable to convert this double value into Date format like "10/11/2016"

I try to use

```
 DateTime newDate = DateTime.FromOADate(currentDate);
```

but it through an exception

> Not a legal OleAut date.

Comment: Why do you expect `10/11/2016` and not `11/10/2016` ? Which one do you think is `Oct 11th 2016` ?

Comment: First of all, who would store a date like that and why? I guess that date means Oct 11th, right? Keep in mind not everybody uses the same format (mm/dd or dd/mm).

Comment: Yes, its Oct 11th 2016

Comment: You know you have wandered down the wrong road when you cant unravel your own dating method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert the double to a string and then call ParseExact specifying the format.

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDate.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

but really you should try to avoid this and store dates in DateTime variables from the start.

Comment: I should avoid this, but I am getting Date as a double value from an API, I am converting in my code to show that in a Date format.

Answer (score 2):

OADate is a number of days since `30 Dec 1899`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx

so `20161011` when treated as OLE Automation Date corresponds to year `57098` (and you have an error). To convert your value in the right way, i.e. to `11 Oct 2016`:

```
double currentDate = 20161011;  
int v = (int) (currentDate + 0.5);

DateTime result = new DateTime(v / 10000, (v / 100) % 100, v % 100);
```

Comment: Why `+ 0.5`? I don't see any benefit from doing that.

Comment: @Andrew: to prevent round up errors when `currentDate` is something like `20161010.9999999999997` (after loading from database/getting from API, processing etc.);

Comment: How I hate that stuff, but I thought that only affected decimals. Whole numbers shouldn't have this issue. Anyway, I don't think (and hope) that "double-date" comes from an operation!

Comment: @Andrew: me to; you're quite right `double currentDate = 20161011;` doesn't have round up errors, but the data's *actual origin* is dubious ("but I am getting Date as a double value from an API" - see comment on Steve's answer), so just in order to be on the safe side I've added +0.5

Answer (score 0):

The OLE Automation Date is not like that, it's a system which (roughly) indicates the days since 1/1/1900.

If I had to do that ugly conversion, I would do this:

```
double currentDate = 20161011;
int intCurrentDate = (int)currentDate;
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(intCurrentDate / 10000, intCurrentDate / 100 % 100, intCurrentDate % 100);
```