# ASP Classic: perform same subtraction of 2 dates and get the same value in C# value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, asp-classic

I am trying to switch from classic ASP to ASP.Net MVC C#. There is a part where my ASP Classic code will get a DateTime Field **A** then will subtract a value **B**  and will get the and answer **14322.4290162037**
   The thing is I don't know how to get the same answer value in **C#**

```
 response.write "A: ==The Value: 19/03/2019 10:17:47==" & rstPASS("DATELASTUSE") & "<br>"
 response.write "B: ==The Value: 01/01/1980 === " & CDate("01/01/1980") & "<br>"
 response.write "A - B: I get: 14322.4290162037 " & rstBROPASS("DATELASTUSE") - CDate("01/01/1980") & "<br>"
```

**What I have tried**

```
 idtLastUse = dt.Rows[0]["DATELASTUSE"] - DateTime.ParseExact(s: "01-01-1980", format: "dd/MM/yy", provider: null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2019, 3, 19, 10, 17, 47);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToOADate() - d2.ToOADate());
```

Look at the documentation for ToOADate to understand why.

Comment: [convert double value into DateTime in c#](//stackoverflow.com/a/39987090)

Answer (score 0):

VB (all flavours) use [OLE Automation date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/35c9bf2d-b8e8-4d7d-a50f-367da0d99fce) format to represent a date in a numeric format.

A brief description would be;

> floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24.

We can verify this ourselves using a quick example;

```vb
<%
Call Response.Write(FormatDateTime(CDate(0), vbLongDate))
%>
```

Depending on your regional settings will return the result;

```
30 December 1899
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Joe's explanation of OLE Automation date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262102/692942)
- [convert double value into DateTime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987090) *(Example of how to use `ToOADate()` to convert a .Net `DateTime` to an OLE Automation date format)*.

Answer (score -1):

**You can substract 2 dates like the following:**

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract (startTime);
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```